# Transforming discontinuous functions for use in neural networks

Tags: transform, neural-network

Are there any general methods of transforming discontinuous functions/values for use in something like a neural network?

---

For example:

Angles are discontinuous from 2pi -> 0, even though the values are essentially the same. The simplest transform I can think of in this case is to convert the angle into a set of minimum angular distances from 3 evenly spaced angles (0, 2/3pi, 4/3pi).

In that case, no two different angles should result in the same three distances, yet two very similar angles should always result in three very similar distances.

While I haven't extensively tested this, the transform seems more suitable when trying to use a minimally complex classifier (such as a single layer neural network).

---

I'm wondering if there is any sort of 'general form' of this style of transformation that could be applied to other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using sin(x) and cos(x)? (It's just the first idea that came to my mind)